# Replaced a Component with another one, build failed with error "Could not resolve project <old component name>"

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I was using react-native-webview-file-upload-android but i wanted to replace it with react-native-webview-android.

I ran the following:

```
npm uninstall react-native-webview-file-upload-android
npm install --save react-native-webview-android
npm link react-native-webview-android
```

and I changed the import in the app.js from

```
import AndroidWebView from 'react-native-webview-file-upload-android';
```

to

```
import WebViewAndroid from 'react-native-webview-android';
```

now when i try npm run android this error occurs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-webview-file-upload-android.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-webview-file-upload-android: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

I tried 
`npm start --clear-cache`, `cd android && gradlew clean`, `npm unlink react-native-webview-file-upload-android`

but none of them worked, why is the old package still erroring here?

Comment: It looks like a linking problem. Sometimes you have to link manually the library because the automatic one is not working always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in my `android/app/build.gradle` and `MainApplication.java`, the old package was still being imported so I removed the import line and it worked